# Zip and move file in Windows 2008R2 Server using Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I want to zip a file E:/logs/MSflexLog.log file using native OS zip (or) 7-zip and the move(cut-paste) into different Directory - F:/Archive/Logs

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I could move the file as it is! But not able to get how to zip

Answer (score 1):

You want the `windows_zipfile` resource from the `windows` cookbook. More info is available in the readme https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/windows#windows_zipfile